# submit a form from a popup to the original window using zend framework

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, popup, submit

I don't know if it is possible, I am using php with zend-framwork and i want to show an editor for the user in a pop-up window.

I want to submit this form back to the original window and close the window.

1)The problem is i cant view the form using `$this->view->form = $form` and echo it in the view of that action ? and i am using this code to popup the new window. i tried to solve this problem by echo the form from the controller,it worked but i couldn't submit anywhere.

```
<a href="#" onClick="MyWindow=window.open('<?php echo $this->url(array('module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'editor'));         ?>','MyWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=600,height=300'); return false;">Click Here</a>
```

2)how to return the pop-up window to the original window or even is that possible?

If my question missing something please ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window.opener property in script of opened popup window.
like this

```
window.opener.TheMethodOfParentWindow(ValueOfTheEditor);
window.close();
```

I have written a detail post here on this topic if you want to check:
http://rupeshpatel.wordpress.com/2012/05/15/how-to-call-javascript-function-of-parent-window-from-new-pop-up-window/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible to submit form from a popup window to the parent window's action.

In my application I used a popup window for editing an offer, it submits to another action in the same controller and after submit the window is closed in 1 or 2 seconds with jQuery, something like 'Offer was edited. Thank you! blah blah...'. The problem with this type of editing is that user can't view the edited offer immediately. He should refresh the 'parent' page to view the changes.

Another way is not using a popup window but popup div in the same page. Then you can submit the form in the same page/action.